# Can not "COPY FROM" with Postgres & Python

Tags: python, postgresql, import, copy, psycopg2

As the topic, this is the code and there is no error message but data did not get insert. 
This is my code, and can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

```
import psycopg2
import sys
import os
import glob 
import csv

#open the csv folder
dictfile='******'
os.chdir(dictfile)
total=[]
for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    total.append(file)
con = None
try: 
    con = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost',database='*****',user='postgres', password='*****') 
    cur = con.cursor()
    for i in range(0,1):   
        filename='/Users/Shared'+'/'+total[0]
        print filename
        #better move all files into shared folder
        x="copy public.crossref_sample from "+ "'"+filename+"'"+" DELIMITERS ',' CSV"
        print x
        cur.execute(x)  
except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
    print 'Error %s' % e    
    sys.exit(1) 
finally:
    if con:
        con.close()
```

Comment: I don't see a commit in your code

Answer (score 6):

As alluded to by @a_horse_with_no_name, you're closing the PostgreSQL database connection, but you're not committing the transaction first.

psycopg2 opens a transaction for you if there isn't one already open. It expects you to commit this transaction when you've finished your work.

Unless you *explicitly* commit a transaction, closing the connection will *rollback* any work that's been done.

Try `con.commit()` after the last copy command.