# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "\"

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a python module which copy data from a table to a file.Im using postgresql as database server. COPY is the command is to be used to do the above action.

However in a blog (http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/058tagtped/about-error-must-be-superuser-to-copy-to-or-from-a-file) it states that, You can use \copy in 'psql' on the client side, but you have to be a superuser to do COPY on the server side, for security reasons. So I used \copy command. When I try to execute the below method, it results in error as

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "\" LINE 1: \copy

I can't find why its throwing error. can someone help me out?

```
def process():
     query="\copy %s TO %s"%('test_table', 'test_file.txt')

     @env.with_transaction()
     def do_execute(db):
         cursor = db.cursor()
         cursor.execute(query)
```

> do_execute is a database wrapper, which creates connection and
>   executes the query.

Comment: `\copy` is a command only recognized by the `psql` command line tool. It is *not* valid SQL. The command line tool most likely implements the command using several SQL constructs to load data then export it to a text file.

Comment: And for that valid SQL - you can find it at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: The same page states: *If you are not using 'psql' and your client library supports it, you can use 'COPY FROM stdin' and pass the data across the client connection.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not "COPY FROM" with Postgres & Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868492/can-not-copy-from-with-postgres-python)

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I replace the line query="\copy %s TO %s"%('test_table', 'test_file.txt') with query='pg_dump table_name > %s'%(txt_file), again I'm facing the same error.

Comment: Where do you see `pg_dump` being used in the dupe I linked you to? That's another command-line tool, **not** a SQL statement.

Comment: You can use one of the copy methods (`.copy_to` in your case): http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from

Comment: @freakish I have tried that method also. But still facing the same error.

Comment: @PSivachandran How exactly are you using it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have tried copy_to, pg_dump, COPY methods to copy table data to a file. But Ended up with same error. can you please tel me a method to do the above action. I have tried googling, but results ended up with error.

Comment: @freakish f = open('filename', 'w')
          query="copy_to(f, 'tablename')". Then the query value will be passed as an argument to the method mentioned above

Comment: @PSivachandran No, use cursor in Python: `cursor.copy_to(f, 'tablename')` (the docs are for the driver)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\` is an escape in Python strings, so your string contains the escape `\c`. However `\c` is an invalid escape in Python, and Python leaves invalid escapes unchanged, so `"\copy"` is just `\copy`. (Thus @tiziano's answer is misleading).

```
>>> print "\c"
\c
```

The real problem is that `\copy` is a `psql` command, not a server side PostgreSQL command. You can't use it with a client other than `psql`. You must instead use [the `psycopg2` support for `COPY`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) to do it via your client driver.

Comment: @Craig.. Thanks for your explanation. I made the changes and make the script to run successfully